# Topological properties of the dual of differential forms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, geometric-measure-theory

Notation:

1. $U \subset R^n$, bounded open set
2. $D^k(U) = \{ \omega : U \to \Lambda^k R^n : \text{compactly supported and infinitely differentiable \}}$
3. $D_k(U) = D^k(U)'$ is the topological dual space (currents)
4. $d : D^k(U) \to D^{k+1}(U)$ is the exterior derivative

The mathematical context is, that $k$-currents $T \in D_k(U)$ provide a generalized notion of $k$-dimensional oriented surface in $\Bbb R^n$, and the flat norm can be used to get a notion of distance between currents.

---

Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be ball and let $\mathcal{D}_0(B)$ be the set of 0-dimensional currents with support in $B$. Recall the flat norm $\mathbb{F}(T)$ of a current $T\in\mathcal{D}_1(B)$ is defined as:
$$
\mathbb{F}(T):=\inf\{\mathbb{M}(T-\partial S)+\mathbb{M}(S):S\in\mathcal{D}_{2}(B)\}.$$

Recall also the definition of *point-finite* collection of sets: A collection $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of a space $X$ is said to be point-finite if every point in the space $X$ belongs to at most finitely many members of $\mathcal{S}$.

I'm trying to prove that the set
$$
X:=\{b\in{\mathcal{D}}_{0}(B): \mbox{ there exists a rectifiable 1-current  }T : \partial T=b\}
$$
has the following property:
For any point-finite open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$, the set $D=\left\{x \in X: \mathcal{U} \text{ is locally finite at } x \right\}$ is a dense set in $X$. I may allow also to prove it for any *countable* point-finite open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ or to find a counterexample.

Comment: Toying around with thing a little, I have an explicit example where $D$ is smaller than $X$, but I fear that won't help me to avoid density. However it got me thinking: Have you tried restricting yourself to currents of the form $\delta_a-\delta_b$ first? This subspace already shows a lot of the features of the flat norm, but you can write down the topology in terms of a and b more directly.

Comment: I guess that density is the most difficult part to avoid with a counterexample, also because we are considering with respect to the (weak) notion of topology induced by the flat norm. May I ask you in which sense would it be helpful to restrict to the two delta currents?